# How can I extract a textfile in R by different condition?

Tags: r, text

I need help for a specific case. 
Having a text file which looks like this.

```
txt1 <-"**Start** Characters I need1 **Stop**. Characters which I don´t neeeeeeeeeeeed. **Starts** Characters I need2 **Stops**. Characters which I don´t neeeeed.
**Start** Character I need3 **Stop**. Characters which I don´t neeeeed."
```

I know how to use the grep function for only one case. But the problem is it stops by the first Stop. 
How I can make sure that it runs until the end of a text. And also note that the pattern is not always Start and Stop, it can be also like Starts and Stops. Maybe grep isn't right for that?

```
    start <- grep("Start", txt1)
    start

    end <- grep("Stop", txt1)
    end

    txt2 <- txt1[start:end]
    txt2
```

Wished result for txt2:

```
Characters I need1 Characters I need2 Start Character I need3
```

I can't find any solution for that in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a nice solution but you can try

```r
stops <- unlist(gregexpr("Stop", txt1))
starts <- unlist(gregexpr("Start", txt1))
txt2 <- character(0)

for (i in 1:length(starts)) {
  txt2 <- paste0(txt2,substr(txt1, starts[i]+5, stops[i]-1))
}
```